# Sending 'void' to parameter of incompatible type 'UIViewController'

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiview, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I create a modal UIView with .xib, and when I click to button, I want display this UIView. But I have an error in the presentViewController : Sending 'void' to parameter  of incompatible type 'UIViewController'. Thanks for your answers.

```
- (void)modal {
    modalViewController *mvc = [[modalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"modalViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIView * modal = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.center.x/2, self.view.center.y/2, 240, 320)];
    modal.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [modal addSubview:mvc.view];
    [self.view addSubview:modal];
}

- (IBAction)showBTN:(id)sender {

    [self presentViewController:[self modal] animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`presentViewController:animated:completion:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController:animated:completion:) first parameter is an instance of `UIViewController` not `void`.

What you are trying to do makes not sense, since you are already adding the view from the `modalViewController` to the current `UIViewControllers` view. So there is no need to call [`presentViewController:animated:completion:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController:animated:completion).

This will add the view to your current view hierarchy:

```
- (IBAction)showBTN:(id)sender {
    [self modal];
}
```

---

Also a small remark, classes should start with a capital letter, so your `modalViewController` class  should actually be named `ModalViewController`.